# Instantiate a System.Type from a type definition string

Tags: c#, configuration, web-config, configuration-files, configurationmanager

In the web.config file, we see a lot of strings following this pattern:

```
    type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, 
System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
```

I want to read this information from the web.config (which I know how to read as a string), and I want to instantiate a type from this string.

Is there some way to do this?

**Update**

I guess I could just do

```
Activator.CreateInstance(System.GetType(stringTypeName))
```

Please confirm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several overloads of [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4.aspx) that enable you to do this. However, you will have to split the string into a type name and assembly name manually.

**Update:** Your own take on this is also correct (although the method is `Type.GetType()`).

Answer (score 0):

It's simple to create an instance of a type using [`Activator.CreateInstance(Type)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx).

*Edit For some reason I though you could just pass the type name - you can't; thanks Jon for pointing this out.*

But you need to get the `Type` from the type name.  If the type name is always fully-qualified (at least down to the assembly name) - then you can simply use:

```
Type t = Type.GetType(typeName);
```

However, that throws an exception if the type can't be found.  You might be better off with:

```
Type t = Type.GetType(typeName, false);
```

And then:

```
object result = null;
if(t != null)
  result = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

*End edit*

However, in some cases that type might not have a default constructor, in which case you either have to skip it (you either catch an exception from `Activator.CreateInstance`, or do a reflection search for the constructor first), or find a way to build the dependant types as well (`Activator.CreateInstance` supports constructors with parameters too - @Jon's answer includes a link).

I don't believe this simple `(Type)` overload I suggest here works with types with constructors that have all-optional parameters, either:

```
public class MyClass {
   public MyClass(string p1 = null, int p2 = 10, ...) { }
}

//...

var o = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyClass)); //<-- will fail
```

Because that's *not* a default constructor - it's up to a compiler to bind such constructors as if they were defaults, by pulling out all the default values into a call to the 'expanded' version.

Comment: I don't see any overload with that signature, can you provide a reference?